# php how to use getimagesize() to check image type on upload

Tags: php, image, upload, filter, mime-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GetImageSize() not returning FALSE when it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464948/getimagesize-not-returning-false-when-it-should)

i currently have a filter system as follows:

```
   // Check to see if the type of file uploaded is a valid image type
function is_valid_type($file)
{
    // This is an array that holds all the valid image MIME types
    $valid_types = array("image/jpg", "image/JPG", "image/jpeg", "image/bmp", "image/gif", "image/png");

    if (in_array($file['type'], $valid_types))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

but i have been told that it is better to check the filetype myself, how would i use the getimagesize() to check the filetype in a similar way?

Comment: [Caution:](http://php.net/manual/function.getimagesize.php) **Do not use** `getimagesize()` to check that a given file is a valid image.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`getimagesize()` returns an array with 7 elements. The index 2 of the array contains one of the `IMAGETYPE_XXX` constants indicating the type of the image.

The equivalent of the function provided using getimagesize() would be

```
function is_valid_type($file)
{
    $size = getimagesize($file);
    if(!$size) {
        return 0;
    }

    $valid_types = array(IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_BMP);

    if(in_array($size[2],  $valid_types)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: thankyou for your reply, but this code returns an error in dreamweaver on the if(!$size){ line

Comment: The third line was missing a semicolon, should be alright now.

Comment: now i get this error Warning: getimagesize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: You should be passing is_valid_type($file) function the filename as the parameter. You are probably giving it an $_FILES array. Try something like is_valid_type($file['name']). Or you could change the "getimagesize($file)" to "getimagesize($file['name'])" so you can call it the same way as the original function. But since the function needs only the filename, it doesn't make sense to have it expect an array.

Comment: thanks, but now i get this error 'getimagesize(538419_10151009993941091_424169609_n.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...'

Comment: The error is quite meaningful in this case: PHP can't find the file in question, most probably because it doesn't exist. You can try printing out the filename `$file` you're passing to `is_valid_type($file)` and see if it exists for yourself. My guess is that the uploaded image is either saved to another folder or it is renamed during the upload. This is up to your implementation of things and not something related to the `is_valid_type` function. That said, my take is that when you call the is_valid_type, the image hasn't yet been moved to it's final location: try `$file['tmp_name']`.

Comment: thankyou this is perfect, you have helped me so much!

Comment: So, to summarize, usage of the above function is:  `is_valid_type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])` if you're checking directly from the $_FILES array. I kinda wish i didn't have to read between the lines just to come to that conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use as below

```
$img_info   = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$mime   = $img_info['mime']; // mime-type as string for ex. "image/jpeg" etc.
```

Comment: Did you test this code ???? you can not use `getimagesize on $_FILES['images']['tmp_name']` it would return `false`

Comment: that is interesting ...  http://codepad.viper-7.com/N96kma it returns `Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty` ... it might be a PHP version specific issue

Comment: that code is susceptible to PHP Exif injection.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check if `getimagesize` returns `false`. If it does, then the file is not a recognised image format (or not an image at all).

Otherwise, get index 2 of the returned array and run it through `image_type_to_mime_type`. This will return a string like "image/gif" etc. See the [docs](http://php.net/image-type-to-mime-type) for more info.