# check if $_FILES is empty or not, file size, file exists

Tags: php

I have an edit form that user can edit his/her information.
it contains firstname, lastname, username, category (which select data from category table) and image inputs. I want a function that can check the image type, size, is empty or not. Actually if the user didn't upload a photo then doesn't need to check it but if the user uploads a photo then the function check its file type(jpg, png, jpeg), and check that file size isn't grater than 1MB.

actually my code works when all of inputs fill out and image uploaded.but if user doesn't upload a photo then this message will appear <>. it is update form so maybe the user uploaded a photo before and he/she doesn't want to change that photo.so my problem is user cant submit his/her information until upload an image.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$Title = test_input($_POST['Title']);
$Category = $_POST['Category'];
$Content = test_input($_POST['Post']);
$Author = test_input($_POST['Author']);
$ref = test_input($_POST['reference']);

$image= $_FILES["img"]["name"];
$imgSize = $_FILES["img"]["size"];
$image_tmp= $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];

$traget_dir = "../files/img/content/";
$target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES["img"]["name"]);
$ImageFileType=pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);



if(empty($Title))
{
    $msg=" * title couldn't be empty";
}
else if(empty($Content))
{
    $msg=" * Content couldn't be empty";
}
else if(empty($Author))
{
    $msg=" * Author couldn't be empty";
}
else if($image =="")
{
    echo $msg=" * you must choose a photo";
    $uploadOK=1;
}

else if($ImageFileType !="jpg" && $ImgeFileType != "gif" &&$ImageFileType     !="png" )
{
    echo $msg=" * only JPG, PNG, GIF are allowed";
}

else if($imgSize > 1024000)
{
    echo $msg= " * the photo shouldn't be greater that 1MB";
}



else if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"],$target_file))
{


     echo $msg1= " * the file ".basename($_FILES['img']['name'])." has been  uploaded";


    $uploadOk = 0;
}

$query= "UPDATE content SET (`Title`='$Title' ,`Text`= '$Content'  ,`Writer`='$Author',`Reference`='$ref',`Image`= '$image')  where Content_ID='$id' ";

 if(mysqli_query($_SESSION['con'],$query))
{
        $msg1="post published";

}
else
    {
        echo $msg="there was an error occured      <br>".mysqli_error($_SESSION['con']);
    }here
```

Comment: First, use [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) function to check whether user uploaded any image or not, and then process your form accordingly.

Comment: You'll have to tell us what doesn't work, do edit that into your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get filesize in bytes by:

```
$_FILES['img']['size']
```

for checking if it's image file or not or image file format you can check `$_FILES['img']['tmp_name']` by [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) like this: [php how to use getimagesize() to check image type on upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12761535/5617911)

for checking if file uploaded or not you can check it with `error`. error number 4 means file not uploaded:

```
if ($_FILES['img']['error']==4){
    echo 'Not uploaded';
}
```

here you can see more information about [Error Messages Number](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: i want if file not uploaded doesn't show any message just continue other codes or submit the form.and check size, type of files when user uploads a file