# Only allow .jpg and .png files only

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I only allow certain filetypes on upload in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486329/how-can-i-only-allow-certain-filetypes-on-upload-in-php)

How can I make the script below only allow .jpg images or .png images?
   It uploads an image directory to a mysql table based on a session username match. Is it possible to restrict the file types? Because I only need .jpg or .png

```
 if ($_POST['submit']) {
    //get file attributes

    $Name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

    if ($Name) {            
    $location = "avatars/$Name";    
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location ) or die('Failed to upload picture'); 
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE fgusers3 SET imagelocation='$location' WHERE name='$name'") or die("Your profile image has been uploaded!");

   }}



echo "Upload your image below:
  <form action='profilepic.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   Profile Picture: <input type='file' name='myfile'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='upload'>
   </form>";
```

Comment: Note there are several way's to spoof extension, mime-type, etc. Be mindful of this fact when dealing with uploaded files.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `pathinfo` & `exif_imagetype`

```
if(pathinfo($Name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION) != "jpg" || exif_imagetype($Name) != IMAGETYPE_JPEG)
{
    // throw error 
}
```

[See More Info to detect Fake Images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10464964/1226894)

Comment: @hakre said that once .....  thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if($_FILES){
    $allowedExtensions = array("jpg","png");

    foreach($_FILES as $key=>$val){
        if(!empty($val['tmp_name'])){
            $ext = end(explode(".",strtolower(basename($val['name']))));
            if(in_array($ext,$allowedExtensions)){
                $file = 'PATH_TO_UPLOAD'.basename($val['name']);

                if(move_uploaded_file($val['tmp_name'],$file)){
                    //SUCCESS_MESSAGE
                }
            }else{
                //FAIL_MESSAGE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`exif_imagetype($tmp_name)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) to check the actual type of the file based on its header. This checks the type based on the contents of the file, so it is the most reliable (e.g. it will give you the right information even if somebody gives you a JPG with a ".png" extension).

There is also the `type` property (`$_FILES['myfile']['type']`), which will give you the MIME type that the browser claims the file is. However, this cannot be trusted if someone maliciously forges the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
$whitelist = array(".jpg",".png");
foreach ($whitelist as $item) {
  if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'])) {
    $uploaddir='uploads/uploads_image/';
    // or code
  }
}
```

Comment: is this secure? esp. against uploading of scripts to RCE?

Answer (score 0):

$imageType = getimagesize($tmp_name);
switch ($imageType['mime'] != "image/jpg" OR $imageType['mim'] != "image/png") { 
    //error code here.
}

It is a bit safer than checking the extension, as the extension can be changed easily. The mime type can be changed as well but requires more knowledge xD

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can limit by file extension, but it's not safe. You can try rename a gif-file and upload it. A little bit safer is using mime-type to detect file type (but still no guarantee). Look at:
[How do I find the mime-type of a file with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134833/how-do-i-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-with-php)

I think more safer is trying to get size of image or if convert to another image type is successful.