# PHP Upload Image formats only?

Tags: php, upload, format, restrict

I have an upload system which will upload files then record in my database. Anyways it works all fine, though how can i make it so that IMAGES only are uploaded and nothing else?

My code:

```
if($_POST[add]){



$dataType = $_POST["dataType"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$fileData = pathinfo(basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]));
$fileName = uniqid() . '.' . $fileData['extension'];
$target_path = ("userfiles/profilepic/" . $fileName);

while(file_exists($target_path))
{
    $fileName = uniqid() . '.' . $fileData['extension'];
    $target_path = ("userfiles/profilepic/" . $fileName);
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_path))
{

  $sql = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users SET `profilepic` = 'userfiles/profilepic/$fileName' WHERE `id` = '".$member["id"]."'");

    $sql->execute();
    $retval = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo "Your profile picture has successfully been updated";


}
else
{
    echo "oh noes.. there was an error :( Please do try again!";
}

}
```

Comment: Spending a few minutes on Google would have given you many results.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry I should have mentioned that I have researched this. I tried many different things but none seemed to work for me. The closest I was at would have been uploading a .png and it come up with This is not an image file. But that just stops.. uploading different formats, what about files that are under the .png, .gif formats?

Comment: Check out this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp under "Restrictions on Upload" codes are available

Comment: @Mobi I checked that out, but did not know how to integrate it into my code.

Comment: [`See this answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2486343/) on SO. @user3370962 - Found after Googling keywords "allow images only upload php" and [`this one`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12864238/)

Comment: [`Another article on the subject`](https://www.stanford.edu/dept/its/communications/webservices/wiki/index.php/How_to_securely_allow_file_uploads_using_the_Stanford_Web_Application_Toolkit)

Comment: @Fred-ii-I found heaps of them. I just dont have an idea how to integrate them into MY code.

Comment: Just place it below your `if($_POST[add]){` then if the conditional statement is `TRUE` then the code keeps going.

Comment: Try what I posted below. @user3370962

Comment: @Fred-ii- Added one, able to upload any files still though? ugh..

Comment: Did you try the answer I posted below? @user3370962

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2486343/)

```
if($_POST[add]){

$file_type = $_FILES['image']['type']; //returns the mimetype

$allowed = array("image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png");
if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed)) {
  $error_message = 'Only jpg, gif, and png files are allowed.';

  echo $error_message;

  exit();

}

$dataType = $_POST["dataType"];

... rest of your code below
```

**Footnotes:**

- [**Other Internet media types**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) should you want to use them in the future.

Comment: Thanks! Worked great.

Comment: Ah good, glad to hear it and you're welcome. @user3370962

Comment: If the answer already exists, then this question should have been marked as a duplicate.

Comment: The OP did not know how to implement it. Do read over the comments under the OP's question. @Joraid - Giving someone a helping hand, is part of SO.

Comment: Yes indeed, it seems the problem was not finding the method, but integrating it.

Comment: Exactly. Sometimes people need a visual method to better understand how. @Joraid