# Upload script to allow only files with PNG extension

Tags: php

How can I make this code such that it allows only PNG files to be uploaded?
Could someone explain it to me?

```
if (isset($_FILES["userfile"]) && !empty($_FILES["userfile"])) {
        $image = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
        $imageName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $imageSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
        $imageType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
        $len = count($image);
        $path = "uploads/furnipack/images/";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
             if (isset($imageName[$i]) && $imageName[$i] !== NULL) {
                 if(move_uploaded_file($image[$i], $path.$imageName[$i])) {
                    $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO imageTable (imageName, imageCategory, imageSize, imageType) VALUES ('$imageName[$i]', '$imageCategory', '$imageSize[$i]' , '$imageType[$i]' )");
                     $melding = "Item is succesvol geupload!";
                 }
             }
        }
}
```

Comment: I have reworded the title and content to improve grammar, removed language name from title as it is not required due to presence of tags. I have also removed the thanks note because it is considered as fluff and is not required to be present in the content.

Answer (score 0):

from the name of the image, get the extension and try to check the image uploaded based on the extension,

```
$imageName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$str=strpos($imageName,'.');
$ext=substr($imageName,$str+1,strlen($imageName)-$str-1);
if($ext=='png')
{
if(move_uploaded_file($image[$i], $path.$imageName[$i])) {
                $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO imageTable (imageName, imageCategory, imageSize, imageType) VALUES ('$imageName[$i]', '$imageCategory', '$imageSize[$i]' , '$imageType[$i]' )");
                 $melding = "Item is succesvol geupload!";
             }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this i guess

```
$ext = pathinfo($imageName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if($ext == "png"){
   if(move_uploaded_file($image[$i], $path.$imageName[$i])) {
            $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO imageTable (imageName, imageCategory, imageSize, imageType) VALUES ('$imageName[$i]', '$imageCategory', '$imageSize[$i]' , '$imageType[$i]' )");
             $melding = "Item is succesvol geupload!";
         }
}
else {
    echo 'please upload .png images only';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question has been answered numerous times on stack overflow, simply check the extension of the image and for a more secure site you may also want to check the exif data discussed in these pages below
[Only allow .jpg and .png files only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864171/only-allow-jpg-and-png-files-only)
[How can I only allow certain filetypes on upload in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486329/how-can-i-only-allow-certain-filetypes-on-upload-in-php)